# RecyclerView and java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, indexoutofboundsexception, android-viewholder

I have a `RecyclerView` that binds a grocery item. Adding the item works perfectly. However, when I try to delete the item the app crashes and I get the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` error.

The problem I am facing is in my `onBindViewHolder()`. I tried to get the adapter position and that did not solve the problem. I also just tried using `notifyDataSetChanged()` and that just deleted my entire list.

My question is what am I doing wrong and how do I fix this problem?

Here is the Adapter class:

```
private class GroceryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GroceryHolder>{
    private List<Grocery> groceries;
    private GroceryHolder holder;

    public GroceryAdapter(){
        setGroceries(GroceryList.get(GroceryActivity.this).getGroceries());
    }

    public void setGroceries(List<Grocery> groceries){
        this.groceries = groceries;
    }

    @Override
    public GroceryHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater= LayoutInflater.from(GroceryActivity.this);
        View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grocery_list_row, parent, false);
        holder =new GroceryHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final GroceryHolder holder, final int position){
        final Grocery grocery = groceries.get(position);
        holder.bindGrocery(grocery);
        //private Grocery grocery;
        holder.deleteImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                GroceryList groceryList = GroceryList.get(getApplicationContext());
                groceryList.deleteGrocery(grocery);
                groceryAdapter.setGroceries(GroceryList.get(getApplicationContext()).getGroceries());
                //holder.getAdapterPosition();
                groceryAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                groceryAdapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(position, groceries.size());

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return groceries.size();
    }
}
}
```

Here is the logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{426a0900 position=0 id=-1, oldPos=1, pLpos:1 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent}
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:5297)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5479)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3534)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3310)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3844)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15745)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15745)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15745)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15745)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15745)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15745)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15745)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2356)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2069)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6624)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:812)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:612)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:582)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:798)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you please explain why do you need `groceryAdapter ` inside your `Adapter` class and where do you create that instance?

Answer (score 6):

You should not pass `final int position` to your anonymous `new View.OnClickListener()`

Instead, use `holder.getAdapterPosition()`:

```
private class GroceryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GroceryHolder> {
        private List<Grocery> groceries;

        public GroceryAdapter(List<Grocery> groceries) {
            this.groceries = groceries;
        }

        @Override
        public GroceryHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater= LayoutInflater.from(GroceryActivity.this);
            View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grocery_list_row, parent, false);
            holder = new GroceryHolder(view);
            return holder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final GroceryHolder holder, int position){
            int safePosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            final Grocery grocery = groceries.get(safePosition);
            holder.bindGrocery(grocery);

            holder.deleteImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // delete item from the list
                    groceries.remove(safePosition);
                    groceryAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(safePosition);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount(){
            return groceries.size();
        }
    }
```

In addition, there are few more unrelated issues:

1. it would be better to set `setOnClickListener` not in `onBindViewHolder`, but in `onCreateViewHolder`
2. Code around setting the list of groceries in constructor looks too complex. Could be much simpler to pass this list as an argument from your Activity/Fragment.
3. `private GroceryHolder holder` as instance variable is unnecessary

Here is more context on `holder.getAdapterPosition()` https://youtu.be/imsr8NrIAMs?t=2092